# The formal way of saying "keep away from"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, formal-language

What's the legal term for *"keep away from"* / *"keep a distance from"*? I'm looking for a verb that means/expresses such a concept.

What I really want is not the legal term but what those people says in law-related TV dramas, that sounded fancy when I heard them. E.g.:

> Due to the conflict of interest, I decided to ( *keep away*  ) from this matter.

I think I've heard such conversation/situation many many times, in all different TV series, but just forgot what that fancy word they use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [*refrain*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refrain) though it's mostly used for verbs (and 'matter' is a noun):

> : to keep oneself from doing, feeling, or indulging in something and especially from following a passing impulse
>   // *refrained* from having dessert

(source: Merriam-Webster)

As for your new examples,

> - I decided to refrain from participating
> - I decided to refrain from getting involved

sound fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the swift answer. Due to the lack of judgement, I normally come back a week to accept the most voted answer. Please understand -- i'm not ignoring everyone's answer, to put it another way.

Comment: Any one who down-voted this, care for an explanation pls?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps those who did are noticing that "refrain" is more typically used in front of "from +[a gerund]" but the OP asked for something to precede a noun.  Or perhaps not - I don't know, because I am not among them.

Comment: Glorfindel, I understand _"refrain from getting involved"_ is OK, but OK to say _"refrain from participation"_?

Comment: Almost, see the updated answer. Participation is a noun :)

Answer (score 1):

> Due to the conflict of interest, I decided to ( keep away ) from this matter.

In a legal setting the word might be [recuse](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/recuse) - *to remove from participation in a court case due to potential prejudice or partiality*.

> Due to the conflict of interest, I decided to **recuse myself** from further participation in this matter.

It can be used outside of the courtroom in a joking way - probably because of all those popular courtroom dramas - but it might be a little tricky for a non-native speaker to pull off in conversation. You would only use it in cases where someone has a conflict of interest.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use specialized websites to look up synonyms. For instance, I googled "keep away synonyms", and the first link led me to "[Synonyms of avoid](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/avoid)" (Merriam-Webster)

The word "avoid" in itself is quite official-looking, and might suit your purpose.